# Passenger Headlight Dim and high beams even more dim

Tags: headlight, kia, rio

I own a 2008 Kia Rio. My passenger side headlight was extremely dim. And when I turned the brights on that light was even dimmer. As a result, I assumed it was a burnt out bulb. I went and replaced both bulbs in the car, and it did not fix the issue. I then assumed it was a bad ground. I could not find the ground, so I just ran a wire and grounded it myself, again to no avail. I have checked the fuse with a multimeter and voltage output is the same for both sides of the circuit. Does anyone have any ideas as to what next step I should take?

Comment: Have you measured the voltage into the bulbs which are dim?